# text/html format in codeigniter rest_controller response

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter

I need a response in text/html format in one of the methods of the my web service.

I use the following code, but it returns the string inside double quotation marks:

```
$this->response("test", REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
```

[image: Response]

How can I have the response as this (without quotation marks):

```
test
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you getting the result as in the image? Then what is the question? If you don't get the quotation marks, then just encode as JSON, and you'll have the quotation marks. (string literals are also JSON).

Comment: I want to just return text/html (one word) in one of the methods, without double quotation and json

Comment: I see. I have updated your question so that is clear.

Comment: **Thank you so much**

Comment: set in your controller or function `$this->rest_format = 'html';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set rest default format in REST_Controller config file to `html`

```
$config['rest_default_format'] = 'html';
```

Comment: Thank you, All the web service function are JSON! I just want one of the web service function to be html

Answer (score 0):

If you have others api (others format), please use this code:
http_response_code(200);
echo 'your text';